# Cloudant nest search and view

Tags: lucene, couchdb, cloudant

Being not really familiar with nosql databases, I currently wonder about the following:
I have a lucene search index which searches through the complete database and:

```
function (doc) {
  index("default", doc.name);
  index("name", doc.name, {"store": true, "index": false});
  if (doc.description) {
    index("default", doc.description);
    index("description", doc.description, {"store": true, "index": false});
  }
  if (doc.steps) {
    for (var i = 0; i < doc.steps.length; i++){
      index("default", doc.steps[i].description);
    }
  }
}
```

It should work with user provided queries later on. Now I somehow have to handle restrictions to certain documents. Is it possible to do something like this (sqlish):

```
SELECT id, name, description FROM Table WHERE id IN (<Lucene search>) AND <restriction>;
```

Creating a view on top of the search results.
Is this possible, or is there a more efficient option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create a "view on top of search results", but it is certainly possible to answer your SQL(ish) query with either

- a Lucene index (as long as the fields you need are indexed)
- a MapReduce view

Without knowing too much about what you mean by , I would tackle this as an extension of your existing Lucene search.

The query you specify against your Lucene index can be pretty complex - you can have logic and brackets in there, just like a SQL WHERE clause e.g.

```
q=name:"Bob Smith" AND description:"database expert" AND ( owner:"glynn" OR group_owner:"staff" OR world_owner:"everyone")
```

In the above example, I return documents matching the query but only if one of three "restriction" parameters is met - modelled on the three-tier file ownership of Unix (you may pick another access control scheme).

Comment: Indexing should not be the problem.
Thanks for the suggestion to handle also the permission settings within lucene queries.
Is it possible to redefine the way results are displayed?
Everything stored is shown under `"fields" : { ...}`
Is it possible to completely redefine that?

Comment: the fields are the items you index and add the `store: true` option. You can also add `?include_docs=true` to the query string to return the whole matching document back